# Android: Don't open app after performing notification on-click action

Tags: java, android, notifications

The main part of my app is a service that displays a notification. The GUI of the app is only  used to be able to change some settings. When I click on that notification, some data should be send in the background without opening the app. To do that, I created an invisible activity.

When I open the app (the configuration part) and exit it with the back button, everything works as intended; when clicking on the notification the data is send without opening the app.

When I exit the app with the home button, every time I click the notification the app opens again.

This is my notification and the Intent to call the data activity:

```
PendingIntent toggleLightsIntent = 
    PendingIntent.getActivity(
    this,
    0,
    new Intent(this, HyperionToggleSwitchActivity.class),
    PendingIntent.FLAG_NO_CREATE);

Notification notification = new Notification.Builder(this)
    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
    .setContentTitle("HyperionSwitch")
    .setContentText("Switch lights")
    .setContentIntent(toggleLightsIntent)
    .build();
```

And this is the part where I send the data:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    sendJson(blue);
    finish();
}
```

What do I have to change so the app won't open when clicking the notification?
It's my first app and took me quite a while to get what I have so far...

Comment: Have you tried to simply *not* set the content intent (or supplying `null`)? According to the docs, only a small icon, content title and content text are mandatory when creating a notification. Conceptually, not setting any action would also make more sense than fiddling with invisible activities, imo.

Comment: Huh? How do you suggest performing an on-click action without setting an Intent?

Comment: I apologise sincerely... I must've had a temporary brain meltdown. Ignore my previous comment. What I should've said instead is to have the `PendingIntent` sent directly to your service using [`PendingIntent.getService()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html#getService%28android.content.Context,%20int,%20android.content.Intent,%20int%29) - You don't need any invisible activities or whatsoever.

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I need. Changed the activity to a service, now it's working as intended.

Comment: Unfortunately I now can't mark the question as answered, because you just commented...

Comment: Glad that helped. I've added the suggestion as an answer. Did you end up adding a second service, or leveraging the same one that manages the notification?

Comment: I added a second service, so my code is more modular. When tapping the notification the service is started, performs the action and immediately stopped afterwards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per earlier comment:

You could change your hidden activity into a `Service` (which generally doesn't have any ui), or leverage the service that manages the notification, and have the `PendingIntent` sent directly to that service using [`PendingIntent.getService()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html#getService%28android.content.Context,%20int,%20android.content.Intent,%20int%29) .

Answer (score 0):

Try this code^

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra(MainActivity.FILE_NAME, "somefile");
    PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, 0);
```

Comment: Where does that file come from? I'm not sending any file. It's just raw Json over TCP.